# LayeredGraphPlot: How to remove one arrow from the edge of the LayeredGraph and keeping the other arrows visualized?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I used "LayeredGraphPlot" in the simulation of a schema. I would like to remove the two green arrows while keeping their edges, and the other arrows of the graph.
How should I proceed to control only these two arrows?
Here's my code

````
chart = LayeredGraphPlot[{Style[Labeled["S" -> "E", F], Red, Thick], 
   Style[Labeled["E" -> "S", Subscript[\[Beta], e]], Dashed, Green, 
    Thick], DirectedEdges -> False, 
   Style[Labeled["I" -> "S", Subscript[\[Beta], i] ], Dashed, Green, 
    Thick], Style[Labeled["E" -> "I", Subscript[e, i]], Brown, Thick],
    Style[Labeled["I" -> "H", Subscript[i, h] ], Brown, Thick], 
   Style[Labeled["I" -> "R", Subscript[i, r] ], Dashed, Purple, 
    Thick], Style[Labeled["H" -> "R", Subscript[h, r] ], Dashed, 
    Purple, Thick], 
   Style[Labeled["E" -> "R", Subscript[e, r] ], Dashed, Purple, 
    Thick], Style[Labeled["H" -> "D", Subscript[h, d   ] ], Dashed, 
    Purple, Thick]}, Left, PlotStyle -> {"TemperatureMap", Bold}, 
  DirectedEdges -> True,
  VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  {VertexShapeFunction -> {"S" -> "Square", "R" -> "ConcaveHexagon", 
     "D" -> "ConcaveHexagon"}}, VertexStyle -> colors, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#1, 0.2], 
      Text[#2, #1]} &), VertexSize -> Large, 
  EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White]]


```
````

Comment: add the directive `Arrowheads[0]` in `Style[...]` for the edges you want rendered as line. E.g., `Style[Labeled["E" -> "S", Subscript[\[Beta], e]],    Dashed, Green,Arrowheads[0], Thick]`

Answer (score 3):

You may replace the "->" with [UndirectedEdge] specifically on those two green edges, that makes the edges undirected.

```
chart = LayeredGraphPlot[{
   Style[Labeled["S" -> "E", F], Red, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["E" \[UndirectedEdge] "S", Subscript[\[Beta], e]],
    Dashed, Green, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["I" \[UndirectedEdge] "S", Subscript[\[Beta], i]], 
    Dashed, Green, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["E" -> "I", Subscript[e, i]], Brown, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["I" -> "H", Subscript[i, h]], Brown, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["I" -> "R", Subscript[i, r]], Dashed, Purple, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["H" -> "R", Subscript[h, r]], Dashed, Purple, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["E" -> "R", Subscript[e, r]], Dashed, Purple, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["H" -> "D", Subscript[h, d]], Dashed, Purple, Thick]}
  , Left, PlotStyle -> {"TemperatureMap", Bold}, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
  PerformanceGoal -> 
   "Quality", {VertexShapeFunction -> {"S" -> "Square", 
     "R" -> "ConcaveHexagon", "D" -> "ConcaveHexagon"}}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#1, 0.2], 
      Text[#2, #1]} &), VertexSize -> Large, 
  EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White]]
```

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Charmbracelet, thank you so much! Yes, it helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the directive `Arrowheads[0]` in `Style[...]` for the edges you wish to render as lines:

```
colors = {"S" -> White, "I" -> Yellow, "R" | "D" -> Red}; 

LayeredGraphPlot[{Style[Labeled["S" -> "E", F], Red, Thick], 
  Style[Labeled["E" -> "S", Subscript[β, e]], Dashed, Green, 
   Thick, Arrowheads[0]], 
  Style[Labeled["I" -> "S", Subscript[β, i]], Dashed, Green, 
   Thick, Arrowheads[0]], 
  Style[Labeled["E" -> "I", Subscript[e, i]], Brown, Thick], 
  Style[Labeled["I" -> "H", Subscript[i, h]], Brown, Thick], 
  Style[Labeled["I" -> "R", Subscript[i, r]], Dashed, Purple, Thick], 
  Style[Labeled["H" -> "R", Subscript[h, r]], Dashed, Purple, Thick], 
  Style[Labeled["E" -> "R", Subscript[e, r]], Dashed, Purple, Thick], 
  Style[Labeled["H" -> "D", Subscript[h, d]], Dashed, Purple, 
   Thick]}, 
 Left, 
 PlotStyle -> Bold, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> 
   {"S" -> "Square", "R" -> "ConcaveHexagon", "D" -> "ConcaveHexagon"}, 
 VertexStyle -> colors, 
 VertexSize -> Large, 
 EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you kglr. :)